# How to know Shift key status when a key is pressed in C?

Tags: c, macos, console

I want to write a program that waits until <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd>  is pressed and then it prints "Hello World!". I'm using MacOSX and I want it to be Console-Based.

Answer (score 3):

If "Console-Based" means that the program must run in a terminal, it cannot distinguish <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> from <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>; both produce the same input.

Comment: I think there should be a way!

Comment: a terminal/console would have to be able to distinguish between the two and it just can't.